# Can a dependent clause and a quote make a complete sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

The sentence is "As my Latin teacher said, “Carpe Diem”: seize the day." I added colon just to clarify the Latin quote. Is this a complete sentence?

Comment: John Danes, could you take those doubts somewhere like English Language Learners? Either way, why would "As my Latin teacher said, “Carpe Diem”: seize the day" not be a complete sentence, despite your punctuation?

Answer (score -1):

As my Latin teacher would say, “Carpe Diem.”.

Not sure on the context of the text but from what I can see your sentence should be written in the past-tense, (implied by the "As" at the beginning).

However, if it is present you must change the sentence to, "My Latin teacher said, "Carpe Diem.".